# Is there a way to make a mock timezone for a Selenium test in Django?

Tags: python, django, selenium, unit-testing, timezone

In my selenium test below I'm trying to test my `Analytics` model. I'm using a mock of an `Analytics` model instance from `class AnalyticsFactory`.

When I run this test everything works fine except I get an error for the `timestamp` field in the Analytics model. Note: I'm using `timezone.now()` for this.

It seems like the time from when I run the test and when the time is assigned to the Analytics factory is slightly different. For example this is the error I'm getting:

```
AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 8, 13, 3, 28, 153988, tzinfo=<UTC>) != datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 8, 13, 3, 28, 48016, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

in the error above 153988 and 48016 are different

Is there a way I could set a 'fake' timezone object instead of using `timezone.now()`? Since it seems like 'now' is so precise that I can't get this to work.

---

`test_models.py`:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.tests.factories import UserFactory, AnalyticsFactory
from myapp.models import Analytics

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.admin = UserFactory(
            username='first.last@gmail.com',
            email='first.last@gmail.com',
            password=12345
        )

        self.a1 = AnalyticsFactory(
            user=self.admin,
            timestamp=timezone.now(),
            views=10
        )

   def test_analytics(self):
        a = Analytics.objects.get(id=6)
        self.assertEqual(a.views, 10)
        self.assertEqual(a.user, self.admin)
        self.assertEqual(a.timestamp, self.a1.timestamp) <--- not working
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

`factories.py`:

```
import factory
from myapp.models import Analytics
from user_profile.models import User
import mock

class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        django_get_or_create = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'password'
        )

class AnalyticsFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Analytics
        django_get_or_create = (
            'timestamp',
            'views',
        )
    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
```

`models.py:`

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from user_profile.models import User

class Analytics(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```